# Code First Apprach with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am a PHP Developer in the process of learning Java / Spring MVC / Hibernate. I was wondering if Hibernate supported Code First Approach like Entity is ASP.NET or Doctrine with PHP. All the resources I have seen so far the database if being created first and then you write your classes and XML files. Is it possible to do code first with Hibernate and it generates the database and handles the schema changes? If so can someone link me to a resource explaining how this is done? Thanks in advance.

While I'm thinking about it can Hibernate generate the code based on an existing schema too?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're looking at very old resources. What you want to use instead is JPA 2; it's very strongly based on Hibernate, and Hibernate can run as a JPA provider. With JPA, which is similar to Entity Framework, you create POJOs and annotate their fields to provide directives to the JPA provider about how to handle persistence.

There's [a decent tutorial here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/tutorial-hibernate-jpa-part-1.html), and I encourage you to look at [Spring Roo](http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/) with its aspect-based approach which frees you from having to manage lots of the bookkeeping by hand.

Comment: @Guillermo I'm not sure what you mean by "code-first". Hibernate (and other JPA implementations) will happily autogenerate a SQL schema for you if you want (though I usually prefer to do that by hand).

Comment: @chrylis Can you point me to some documentation? I did some research but it its very hard to find. What I'm looking for is generating migrations like the entity framework can do with its `add-migration` command. Do you mean e.g. liquibase?

Comment: @Guillermo You're looking for `auto-ddl`. Not my preference (I do them by hand, with Flyway if I have the option), but useful for development.