# Does spring framework have a module that creates database tables from Java objects?

Tags: django, spring, hibernate

I am new to Spring framework.  I was trying to see if the framework has modules that create/update database tables from Java objects, similar to what Django python framework does.

If not, is there something comparable to what Django does?

Comment: You're looking for "Code First."  https://stackoverflow.com/q/19531450

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to automatic create table in jpa persistence xml file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32873844/how-to-automatic-create-table-in-jpa-persistence-xml-file)